# Kendo Grid: Problem in translated text inside grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, localization, kendo-grid

I am creating a web app in asp.net-mvc I have a Kendo Grid, the data of the grid is being translated into hindi-(India) language,

The data is translating properly in controller

[image]

controller code looks like below,

```
model.NextActionTooltip = (NextActionObject) == null ? "--" : NextActionObject.HoverText;
gridTextTobeTranslatedList.Add(model.NextActionTooltip);
MyRegistrationsList.Add(model);

MultiLanguageAuthentication multilang = new MultiLanguageAuthentication(SessionManager.MultiLanguageClientId, 

SessionManager.MultiLanguageClientSecret);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionManager.TargetLanguage) && !SessionManager.TargetLanguage.ToLower().Contains("en"))
{
    GridTranslatedText = multilang.TranslateArrayMethod(gridTextTobeTranslatedList.ToArray(), SessionManager.TargetLanguage, SessionManager.SourceLanguage);
    for (int i = 0; i < MyRegistrationsList.Count(); i++)
    {
        MyRegistrationsList[i].Status = GridTranslatedText[MyRegistrationsList[i].Status];
        MyRegistrationsList[i].NextActionTooltip = GridTranslatedText[MyRegistrationsList[i].NextActionTooltip];
    }
}
```

but when I look at my view instead of translated text, (???????) is appearing in my grid

Have a look at my grid[image]

I am calling the function from grid like below

```
.Events(x => x.DataBound("onDataBound")).DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("Registration", "Registrations")).PageSize(ViewBag.PageSize))
```

my network panel[image]

I am not able to understand the problem with kendo grid event for translated text,

What is the problem as per you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest submitting a ticket to Telerik and asking them what the issue is.  This could be a bug inside their translation code.